# MySQL sort by a column by default in phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I added a new index in my table and now phpMyAdmin is sorting the rows by that column by default. How do I make phpMyAdmin sort the rows by the `id` column instead of the `url` column by default?

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `links` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `url` varchar(255) NOT NULL default '',
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `url` (`url`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=343959 ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can resolve this issue by adding default order by to the tableusing the alter table query.

QUERY: **alter table `links` order by id;**

If you not specify any order by clause in where clause, then rows will sort by default "id" column.

Comment: Tables do not have default order. Read MySQL's documentation about ALTER TABLE to see what this statement does - and which cases it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is no "default" ordering of rows.  If you want a query to return rows in a particular order, then you must use an `order by` clause.

You cannot even depend on rows being returned by the primary key order.  In fact, with updates/deletes/inserts on the table, this will often not be true.

If you want a query to return rows in a particular order, then you must use an `order by` clause (I realize I repeated that).  The only exception is that MySQL (in violation of the standard) guarantees the ordering of results when using `group by`.

Comment: This might be a feature of phpMyAdmin then? Before today, phpMyAdmin added `order by id` by default. After adding the index, it now adds `order by url`

Comment: phpMyAdmin does add an `ORDER BY` clause by default, and this actually creates headaches when clicking on the table tree view; we have to kill the query on the server when a very large dataset is hit with that "feature".